# FlowDocumentPageViewer jumps be default to the last page

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I have a FlowDocument that has been populated with a bunch of tables. Then I do,

```
DocumentReader = doc;
```

(DocumentReader is a FlowDocumentPageViewer and doc is FlowDocument)

When I do this, the control jumps to the last page. I tried `DocumentReader.FirstPage()` but then realized that the PageCount is 1. (The FlowDocument is really long; I see hundreds of  pages in the control. Except when it is loaded I see page 344 of 344).

How can I jump to the first page?

Comment: wouldn't it be DocumentReader.Document = doc; ?

Comment: Ya. It is. Oversight. DocumentReader.Document = doc. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
this.DocumentReader.GoToPage(1);
```

Comment: Tried that. The thing is, that after I do `DocumentReader.Document = Doc`, DocumentReader.PageCount is 1 for some reason. Why would this be? Something fundamental about the FlowDocumentPageViewer methinks.

Answer (score 0):

I also have encounted this thing.After checking the viewingmode of the flowdocumnetreader,i find that switching the viewmode from scroll to the page 
will always set  the first pgae as the current page .In fact, u can set flowdocumentreader's
visibility to visible until content inserting is completed  to gain a decent UI transition.

this.docReader.ViewingMode = FlowDocumentReaderViewingMode.Scrol
this.docReader.ViewingMode = FlowDocumentReaderViewingMode.Page;

good luck!